# dc.js and dc.leaflet.js; wrong type of map returned

Tags: leaflet, dc.js, dc.leaflet.js

I'm trying to make a dashboard using `dc.js`. It has a few charts and a choroplethChart. It all worked fine, but I needed to add leaflet to the map. I've followed [this sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe2Ga.png) and used `dc.leaflet.js` library, but instead of choroplethChart it returns Markers (see picture)[image]

(this is how it looked before using leaflet) [image]
The code is below and [this is where geojson resides](https://github.com/oobrien/vis/blob/master/tube/data/tfl_stations.json):

```
var usChart = dc_leaflet.choroplethChart("#us-chart");

usChart.width(1000)
    .height(450)
    .dimension(stateDim)
    .group(totalDemandByStation)
    .center([ 51.4963, -0.143 ])
    .zoom(11)
    .geojson(statesJson)
    .colors(["#E2F2FF", "#C4E4FF", "#9ED2FF", "#81C5FF", "#6BBAFF", "#51AEFF", "#36A2FF", "#1E96FF", "#0089FF", "#0061B5"])
    .colorDomain([0, max_state])
    .colors(['#fff7ec','#fee8c8','#fdd49e','#fdbb84','#fc8d59','#ef6548','#d7301f','#b30000','#7f0000'])
    .colorAccessor(function(d,i) {
          return d.value;
      })
    .featureKeyAccessor(function(feature) {
          return feature.properties.name;
      })
    .renderPopup(true)
    .popup(function(d,feature) {
          return feature.properties.name+" : "+d.value;
      })
    .legend(dc_leaflet.legend().position('bottomright'));

    //https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/419
    usChart.on("preRender", function(chart) {
        chart.colorDomain(d3.extent(chart.data(), chart.valueAccessor()));
    })
    usChart.on("preRedraw", function(chart) {
        chart.colorDomain(d3.extent(chart.data(), chart.valueAccessor()));
    })
```

Comment: That is very strange. Do you mean that you followed [the example on the main page](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.leaflet.js/)? Can you share a complete example to help us troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert here, but the choropleth is expecting map data rather than point data. The features in your geojson are points:

```
{
    "crs": {
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        },
        "type": "name"
    },
    "features": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                    -0.013071299999987,
                    51.510716
                ],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "properties": {
                "id": "940GZZDLALL",
                "labelX": 30,
                "lines": [
                    {
                        "name": "DLR"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "All Saints",
                "tfl_intid": 850
            },
            "type": "Feature"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                    0.061052699999989,
                    51.51427850000001
                ],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "properties": {
                "id": "940GZZDLBEC",
                "labelX": -30,
                "lines": [
                    {
                        "name": "DLR"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "Beckton",
                "tfl_intid": 895
            },
            "type": "Feature"
        },
...
```

To draw a choropleth, Leaflet will need features whose `type`s are Polygon.

So my guess is that Leaflet is punting and drawing markers

Comment: So you think it's a leaflet restriction? that would make it a bit difficult to fix then. I've added a picture of how it looks using pure dc.js

Comment: slightly unrelated question, but do you know why the map is not being filtered based on the destination selection (bottom bar chart)? The map can filter other plots, but not vice versa.

Comment: No I mean that you have to provide the outlines of the regions you want to display. See the dc.leaflet.js example, where it uses outlines of the states of Bulgaria. So you probably want outlines of the post codes around London, for example. And if this is your data, you'll have to aggregate it based on those regions.